# Trigger not running for Stored Procedure Activity in azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a Activity Stored Procedure1.
it is running fine when i manually run.
it is running fine with Trigger Now.

but schedule trigger not running. I have only one activity in my pipeline Stored Procedure1

below is trigger code

```
{
"name": "trigger1",
"properties": {
    "runtimeState": "Started",
    "pipelines": [
        {
            "pipelineReference": {
                "referenceName": "pipeline3",
                "type": "PipelineReference"
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
    "typeProperties": {
        "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 6,
            "startTime": "2019-01-10T20:47:00.000Z",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#schedule-trigger-definition), I think your trigger did not be triggered because of the limitation of Azure Data Factory.

***Official statement:***

> The parameters property is a mandatory property of the pipelines
>   element. If your pipeline doesn't take any parameters, you must
>   include an empty JSON definition for the parameters property.

So, according to your code, you missed the `parameters` property. Please add it even though you don't have it, and the trigger will be executed normally.

Comment: Thanks for replay, i try to add a dummy parameter in code of trrigger but it's not allow to edit in trigger code

Comment: Now,
My Trigger is working,

i am adding dummy parameter in PiplineCode  not in TriggerCode  "parmater":{}

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this if it helps to someone...
I had the similar issue and tried this option of creating dummy variable in pipeline, but the issue was when I deploy the code to other environment(dev-->test/ppe/prod), i was getting the error like 'instance of an object not set properly' (and I have azure function activity in my adf pipeline, and this is where i was getting this error). So I tried creating dummy header under 'settings' in azure function activity and deployed,trigger worked this time as expected. Hope this helps.